# How to monitor windows manchine in grafana using prometheus?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I am monitoring windows machine and i installed wmi exporter in my machine. I am using prometheus and grafana as monitoring tools. which query i should use to monitor the CPU status of my windows machine

Answer (score 3):

This gets you the percentege of CPU use.

```
100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(wmi_cpu_time_total{mode="idle", instance=~"$server.*"}[1m])) * 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a WMI exporter running , but [according to its documentation](https://github.com/martinlindhe/wmi_exporter/blob/master/docs/collector.cpu.md) something like this should work with a stacked graph:

```
sum by(mode) (rate(wmi_cpu_time_total[5m]))
```

You can add labels to the metric to filter by `instance` / `job` / whatever and you can tweak the range that you compute the `rate` over (e.g. `1m` for less smoothing; `1h` over longer ranges of time; or Grafana's `$__interval` for dashboard range + screen resolution dependent graphing).

**Edit:** the query above would give you CPU usage in absolute terms, i.e. if your machine had 4 cores, the stacked graph would add up to (approximately) 4 or 400%. If you want it to instead add up to exactly 100% you should use something like this (not tested):

```
sum by(mode) (rate(wmi_cpu_time_total[5m]))
  /
scalar(sum(rate(wmi_cpu_time_total[5m]))
```

All it does is it divides each per-CPU-mode value by their sum, so the results will always sum up to 1. All you need to do in Grafana is select the unit of measurement to be "percentage (0-1)".

Comment: Does the above query gives CPU usage percentage? I need to monitor CPU usage which some time going upto 90%

Comment: It will give you the "number of CPUs in each state". So if you had a machine with 4 CPUs that were 60% "user", 30% "privileged" and 10% "idle" over the past 5 minutes, you'd get `{mode="user"} 2.4`; `{mode="privileged"} 1.2`; and `{mode="idle"} 0.4`. I'll edit my response and add a query that should return percentages instead.